# Algorithm and program for modelling a Free Nilpotent Lie algeabra

Tags: lie-algebras, mathematica, nilpotence, sagemath

I need to compute in a Free Nilpotent Lie Algebra $L$ given by a finite list of generators. For example, put the generators $\{A, B\}$. So, the linear generators for the space of $L$ is
$$\{A, B, [A,B], [A, [A,B]],\cdots\}$$
all expressions of depth  $\le N$.

But it is needed to construct from this a basis $\{e(1) ... e(m)\}$ of the space of $L$ and to find the table of  $[e(i), e(j)]$, with bringing the results to a canonical form.

Probably there are known algorithms for this and also program libraries
(for example, for FriCAS (Axiom), Sage, Mathematica, Maple ...).

Please, who can advise?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Finding a basis for a free nilpotent Lie algebra is basically the same problem as finding a basis for a free Lie algebra, since you only need to ignore the bracket expressions above the nilpotency step. For a free Lie algebra, a basis can be found by considering any [Hall set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_word), such as the [Lyndon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word). A good reference for these things is chapter 4 of Reutenauer's book Free Lie Algebras.

For example consider the free nilpotent Lie algebra with 2 generators $A$ and $B$ of nilpotency step 4. The Lyndon words with letters $A$ and $B$ up to length 4 are
$$A,B,AB,AAB,ABB,AAAB,AABB,ABBB.$$
To find the corresponding basis elements of the free nilpotent Lie algebra, we look at the [standard factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word#Standard_factorization) $w=uv$ of each word $w$, which are
\begin{align}
AB&=(A)(B),&
AAB&=(A)(AB),& 
ABB&=(AB)(B),\\
AAAB&=(A)(AAB),&
AABB&=(A)(ABB),&
ABBB&=(ABB)(B)
\end{align}
From these, we can read off the basis of the free nilpotent Lie algebra, where the Lie bracket corresponding to a word $w=uv$ is the Lie bracket $[u,v]$, with the Lie brackets corresponding to $u,v$ determined recursively. So in this case we obtain the basis
\begin{align}
A,
B,
[A,B],
[A,[A,B]],
[[A,B],B],
[A,[A,[A,B]]],
[A,[[A,B],B]],
[[[A,B],B],B].
\end{align}
The computation of Lie brackets is a bit more tricky to describe, but essentially amounts to applying anticommutativity and the Jacobi identity in a systematic fashion using the ordering of Hall words. The precise formalism is in terms of [rewriting rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_word#Term_rewriting) for sequences of Hall words and I would recommend looking at Reutenauer's text for the details.

To give an example in the above setting, consider the Lie bracket $[AAB,B]$ of the basis elements $AAB=[A,AB] = [A,[A,B]]$ and $B$. The element $[AAB,B]$ does not appear in the basis, so it must be a linear combination of some other elements. Applying the Jacobi identity, we obtain
$$[AAB,B] = [[A,AB],B] = -[[AB,B],A]-[[B,A],AB].$$
By anticommutativity, we have
$$[[B,A],AB]=[-AB,AB] = 0$$
and
$$[[AB,B],A] = [ABB,A] = -[A,ABB]=-AABB$$
so we conclude that $[AAB,B] = AABB$. Of course in general the brackets computed in this way can lead to more complicated linear combinations.

Regarding program libraries, free nilpotent Lie algebras have implementations at least in [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/algebras/sage/algebras/lie_algebras/nilpotent_lie_algebra.html) and in [GAP](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap64.html#X79FD70C487EA9438).

Comment: There also is a letter from StackOverflow (?) which suggests M.Grayson.
"Models for Free Nilpotent Lie Algebras". 1990. I shall gratefully consider both answers.